# segfault on fgets... sometimes

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, fgets

I'm getting a segmentation from fgets, but only sometimes. It's someone else's code, and I don't understand the makefile, so I'm debugging with printf statements... I put this at two parts of the main function: (I only create the variables *f and line once, but I fopen and fclose the file both times.)

```
FILE *f = NULL;
char line[1000];
if ((f=fopen(filename,"r+"))==NULL)
{
     printf("Error opening file\n");
     f=0;//...handle error... //(usually just call abort() or return -1
}
//f = rfopen(fname, "r+");
printf("f from eval_args: %d, filename %s\n",f,filename);
printf("trying to read from file...\n");
printf("%s\n",fgets(line, sizeof (line), f));
printf("...succeeded\n");
fclose(f);
```

which gives me two different outputs:

```
f from eval_args: 4609600, filename /correct/path/to/file
trying to read from file...
 100

...succeeded

f prior to entering density profile: 4609600, filename /correct/path/to/file
trying to read from file...
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I check that the file is correctly opened, and guard against reading more characters than will fit in 'line'. I saw in one forum that the filename shouldn't be more than 49 characters long... but a) that's a strange restriction and b) why does it work the first time?

Does anyone know what else I could check?

Comment: Doesn't printf() print `(null)` upon encountering a NULL string?

Comment: Could you post a small compilable program that reproduces the problem?

Comment: First you should put the `fgets` as a separate statement, and then you should use the debugger to help you locate and examine the error.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions @Joachim, I put fgets on its own line and the segfault is definitely there. Now I've just got to figure out why that low-level function gives non-reproducible behaviour for identical input...

Comment: @H2CO3, from a quick google search, it seems it's not well defined, but for me, printf("%s \n",NULL) also causes a segfault, so I may have had two issues before.

Comment: @craq - the segfault is occurring in the call to `fgets` itself?  If so, make sure your file handle `f` hasn't been closed or overwritten.

Comment: @H2CO3 - the behavior upon attempting to dereference an invalid pointer value (including NULL) is undefined; it will often (but not always) manifest as an access violation or segfault. `printf` expects the arguments corresponding to each conversion specifier to be valid and of the correct type and, in the case of the `%s` conversion specifier, not NULL.

Comment: I know that dereferencing NULL is undefined, but AFAIK most libc implementations check for NULL before. Anyway, it seems not to be the solution...

Comment: do this: printf("%s\n", ((p = fgets(line, sizeof (line), f)) == NULL) ? "** NULL **" : p);  (you will have to declare 'char *p;'

Comment: Which operating system is this code on?

Comment: @thkala it's a solaris operating system. On GNU/Linux I get `*** glibc detected *** ./myTest: munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x00002b86b85abfc0 ***`

Comment: @Alex, that either works or segfaults, depending on where I put it in my code... The segfault must be due to something that happens in the rest of my program, but since neither `line` nor `filename` nor the file itself is changed, I can't see what else would make the difference.

Comment: thanks everyone for all the answers, it turned out to be a memory leak. Specifically, a secondary pointer was used to write on memory which really belonged to another pointer, and then freed at another part of the program (between the 1st and 2nd time I called the code above). I guess that's why printf still worked on all the variables, but writing to them was illegal?

Answer (score 1):

If it is not to much of a hassle you could, but guess you know, do something like;

*Could be beautified a bit, but*:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

#define MAX_LINE    1024

void dbg_fprnt(FILE *fh, char *fmt, ...)
{
    char buf[MAX_LINE];
    char inf[MAX_LINE] = {0};
    va_list args;

    if (fmt && *fmt) {
        va_start(args, fmt);
        va_end(args);
        vsprintf(inf, fmt, args);
    }

    buf[0] = '\n';
    buf[1] = '\0';
    if (ferror(fh)) {
        fprintf(stderr, " * ERR, ferror() --- \n");
    } else if (fh == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,
            " * DBG PRNT ERR;; Trying to print from NULL ---\n");
    /* else if (and so forth) */
    } else {
        if (fgets(buf, MAX_LINE, fh) == NULL) {
            perror(" * ERR DBG PRNTF FGETS, --");
        }
    }
    printf("%-15s FC:: %s", inf, buf);
}

int main(void)
{
    char *fn = "lorem_ipsum";
    FILE *fh;

    if ((fh = fopen(fn, "r")) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,
            "Unable to open '%s' for read.\n",
            fn);
        return 1;
    }

    setbuf(stdout, NULL);

    dbg_fprnt(fh, "SOME LINE: %d", 123);
    dbg_fprnt(fh, "%s", "SASA");
    dbg_fprnt(fh, "");
    dbg_fprnt(fh, NULL);
    dbg_fprnt(fh, "%s %d !", "Woot", 33);
    dbg_fprnt(fh, "@%d :::", __LINE__);
    fclose(fh);
    dbg_fprnt(fh, "@%d :::", __LINE__);


    return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
./fe
SOME LINE: 123  FC:: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod 
SASA            FC:: tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                FC:: quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo 
                FC:: consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse 
Woot 33 !       FC:: cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non 
@52 :::         FC:: proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
 * ERR DBG PRNTF FGETS, --: Bad file descriptor
@54 :::         FC::
```

Comment: wow, thanks for that, I did learn a bit. I get slightly different output to you, but that probably doesn't matter. Especially since it doesn't apply to fgets. For me, the last 3 lines of the output look like: `@62 :::         FC:: proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.`
    `* ERR DBG PRNTF FGETS, --: Bad file number`
    `@64 :::         FC:: `

Comment: @craq: `__LINE__` , `__FILE__` etc are preprocessor macros and yield linenumber etc in _your_ file. So in _my_ file the "`dbg_fprnt(fh, "@%d :::", __LINE__);`" before fclose(fh) was on line 52, in _your_ file it was on line 62.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, the probable reason maybe the second `fgets` doesn't success, so it returns `NULL`, which caused a segment fault. Then why the second `fgets` fail? You may take a look at it...

Referring to `fgets` spec:

> > On success, the function returns the same str parameter.
> >     If the End-of-File is encountered and no characters have been read, the contents of str remain unchanged and a null pointer is returned.
> >     If an error occurs, a null pointer is returned.
> >     Use either ferror or feof to check whether an error happened or the End-of-File was reached.
> >     http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fgets/

So generally it's not a good practice to directly use the return value of `fgets`.

Comment: thanks for the tip, I've put the fgets and printf calls on separate lines now, and it seems the fgets function doesn't return at all. (Segfaults before it even gives a NULL output.)

Comment: @craq - make sure you haven't inadvertantly closed or overwritten your file handle `f` before the `fgets` call.

Comment: @John - deliberately closing it, overwriting it and opening it again should be ok, right?

Answer (score 0):

From your print out:

```
f from eval_args: 4609600, filename /correct/path/to/file
trying to read from file...
 100

...succeeded

f prior to entering density profile: 4609600, filename /correct/path/to/file
trying to read from file...
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

You have "f prior to entering density profile" instead of "f from eval_args", but "f prior to entering density profile" does not exist in the source your provided, I think you are not running the same code.

and for the comment "//...handle error... //(usually just call abort() or return -1" there is no code to handle it, so it can still go down and coredump.

From description of return from fgets:

Upon successful completion, fgets() shall return s. If the stream is at end-of-file, the end-of-file indicator for the stream shall be set and fgets() shall return a null pointer. If a read error occurs, the error indicator for the stream shall be set, fgets() shall return a null pointer, and shall set errno to indicate the error.

So an EOF or anything bad would make that printf coredump.

I suggest something along the lines of:

```
    FILE *f = fopen(filename,"r+");
    if (f) {
        char line[1000];
        printf("f from eval_args: %p, filename %s\n",f,filename);
        printf("trying to read from file...\n");
        while(fgets(line, sizeof (line), f)) printf("%s",line);
        fclose(f);
    }
    else printf("Error opening file\n");
```

Comment: yes, I changed the string output so I could easily tell where the output came from. And yes, it's lazy not to handle the error, but if that were the case I would at least know because of the printf statement. Just to reiterate, it's the fgets call, not the printf that generates the segfault. I now have `char *dummy; dummy=fgets(line, sizeof (line)-1, f); printf("fgets has returned\n"); ...` and the segfault occurs before printing that line.